# Code abstraction in scala

Tags: scala, abstraction, higher-order-functions

The first code is my first draft solution to an exercise from the web, it works fine (passes all the tests), but has a lot of duplicate code. 
So I proceeded to abstract the functions and I got the second item, which I think should work equally, but it does not (it just passes a few), what am I doing wrong?

1)

```
 class Anagram(strg: String) {

  def matches(words: Seq[String]): Seq[String] = {
    def stylisticDifference(things: Seq[String], text: String): Seq[String] = {
      things.filter(w => w.toLowerCase == text.toLowerCase)
    }
    def essensialSimlitude(things: Seq[String], text: String):Seq[String] = {
      things.filter(w => w.toLowerCase.sorted == text.toLowerCase.sorted)
    }
    essensialSimlitude(words,strg) diff stylisticDifference(words,strg)

  }
}
```

2)

```
class Anagram(strg: String) {
  def matches(words: Seq[String]):Seq[String] = {
    def answer(things: Seq[String], text: String, fn: String => String): Seq[String] = {
      things.filter(w => fn(w.toLowerCase) == fn(text.toLowerCase))
    }
    val stringSort = (s: String) => s.sorted
    answer(words,strg, identity) diff answer(words, strg, stringSort)
  }
}
```

Comment: What is failing in the second one?  What should it do and what is it doing instead?

Comment: change `w => fn(w.toLowerCase) == fn(text.toLowerCase)` to `w => fn(w).toLowerCase == fn(text).toLowerCase` . As `sorting then lowercase` result will be different from `lowercase then sorting`

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

change this

```
answer(words,strg, identity) diff answer(words, strg, stringSort)
```

to this:

```
answer(words,strg, stringSort) diff answer(words, strg, identity)
```

Explanation:

http://alvinalexander.com/scala/union-intersection-difference-scala-sets

Diff in mathematics is not commutative.